# Ruby Mocking IO - issue with select

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, io, mocking

I have been learning Ruby, and have ran into a problem. I am building a game of battleships to learn the language.

The game takes 2 input and 2 output streams into the constructor (allowing two clients to play from the same terminal, both from network connections, or one from each)

This works fine for the game itself, however as I am also practicing working in a test driven development way. This has caused an issue - for testing (rspec) I mock an IO object for input and output

```
@outputIO = mock("io")
@inputIO = mock("io")
```

This works great for the majority of the work, however certain sections require the use of the select command, so that both players can be inputing information at the same time:

```
result = select([@p1_input,@p2_input], nil, nil)
for r in result[0]
  if r == @p1_input || r == @p2_input
    input = r
  end
end
```

@p1_input and @p2_input are set in the constructor. When running the rspec tests I get:

```
TypeError: can't convert RSpec::Mocks::Mock into IO
```

How can I mock IO so that this functions correctly? Instead of mocking should I create a new instance of IO and override the gets method? Would that suffice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when doing IO for testing i like using StringIO: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html

when you are relying on low level methods like select, i think it's not a really good idea to mock or stub out those parts. you won't get anything form that. try to do the real stuff in your tests but refactor out all the logic from within there, so that you can have normal test for that.

Comment: no, but you could use `IO.pipe` to create channels for the test

Comment: Hmm... a bit heavyweight compared to a mock, but yes.

Comment: @UncleMikey i think you are not getting my point. i'm advising against using mocks here. a test-double is much better suited for those kind of io operations. in my experience mocking on such a low level results in tests that actually don't protect against anything, giving a false feeling of confidence of your code while it's broken.

Comment: I misspoke actually.  I agree with you. I just don't want to have to write that double myself :-) I was rather surprised to find there was not already something useful in rspec, for example.